# How to enable keyboard shortcut on an iFrame

Tags: reactjs

I have an iframe inside my react app where I'm loading google docs to copy some content into my internal tool. But when I use CTRL + C, content is not getting copied. How to enable keywords shortcut on iframe using React.

```
 <iframe style={{width:"40vw", height:"100vh"}} src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ytCdWClP-fqY21uQ7CHFJFG2d6KIcCtCnnNt_8KQwZo/edit?usp=sharing" frameBorder="0" ref={iframeRef} />
```

[image: iFrame]

Answer (score 1):

Add an onLoad event handler to the iframe element to set up the keydown event listener once the iframe is loaded.

And handleKeyDown function checks whether the ctrlKey and "C" key are pressed and then calls the document.execCommand("copy") method to copy the selected content to the clipboard.

Note that the document.execCommand method might not work in some browsers, and you may need to use a different method to copy the content to the clipboard.

```js
import React, { useRef } from "react";

export default function IframeComponent() {
  const iframeRef = useRef(null);

  const handleIframeLoad = () => {
    const iframe = iframeRef.current;
    const iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

    iframeDocument.addEventListener("keydown", handleKeyDown);
  };

  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.code === "KeyC") {
      document.execCommand("copy");
    }
  };

  return (
    <iframe
      ref={iframeRef}
      src="https://docs.google.com/document/d/your-doc-id/edit?usp=sharing"
      onLoad={handleIframeLoad}
    />
  );
}
```

Comment: My PDF loading is slightly differently as you can see in the post.

Comment: What do you mean different ? I have url 2 in my demo . if you think it is right . You can use it .  
  const url2 =
    "https://docs.google.com/document/d/1ytCdWClP-fqY21uQ7CHFJFG2d6KIcCtCnnNt_8KQwZo/preview?pli=1"